# Is it possible to get Model Name and field name out of properties?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I try to subclass ndb property as the following example

```
class FileStorageProperty(ndb.StringProperty):

    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super(FileStorageProperty, self).__init__(**kwds)

    def _to_base_type(self, value):
        # Do somethings to get field name and model name
        return None

    def _from_base_type(self, value):
        return None
```

so the way to using FileStorageProperty is somethings like

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    file = FileStorageProperty()
```

What I would like to do is, inside of FileStorageProperty Class eg. init, _to_base_type, _from_base_type I would like to know model name ('A') and field name ('file').

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Where is FileStorage Class? There is only FileStorageProperty class in your example, not clear about what you want :)

Comment: apologize for my mistake, I mean inside the FileStorageProperty class. I just edit the question for better understanding.

Comment: You can't.. since you are creating object for `FileStorageProperty` class   inside another class A, then how come the class A availabe within FileStorageProperty class. Bi-directional way isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to pass the information as arguments. You might have to pass the name of the class and the name of the field as strings since I suspect the class doesn't exist at the point that you are creating the field.

```
class FileStorageProperty(ndb.StringProperty):

    def __init__(self, model, field, **kwds):
        self._model = model
        self._field = field
        super(FileStorageProperty, self).__init__(**kwds)

class A(ndb.Model):
    file = FileStorageProperty("A", "file")
```